# How To Name A Boat With No Gravity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft I want to summon a boat with a specific name and the no gravity tag, which gets rid of gravity for the boat. This is easy separately, but I can't figure out how to do them together.

This is what I have so far:

```
/Summon Boat [{NoGravity:1}Name:boat]
```

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: @Jim Jones Im trying to sommo a boat with the no gravity tag, wich gets rid of gravity and a name, which are easy seperatly but I can't figure out how to get them together, this is what I have so far: /Summon Boat [{NoGravity:1}Name:boat]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple. If the boat is already existing you can stand within 5 blocks of it and execute:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Boat,r=5] {NoGravity:1,CustomName:Name,CustomNameVisible:1}
```

If you want it in a summon command, use:

```
/summon Boat ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1,CustomName:Name,CustomNameVisible:1}
```